# How to Join two table in mysql and display it using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. The structure is :

```
mysql> desc working;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| worker_id   | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| worker_duty | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| salary      | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc users;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | varchar(12)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| user_name   | varchar(21)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| discription | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to join this two table using `worker_id` and `user_id` and fetch it using PHP.

I use :

```
SELECT * from users t1
WHERE user_id="293274"
AND SELECT worker_duty ,worker_id from working t2
             WHERE t1.user_id= t2.worker_id
```

But this code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inner join

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, u.discription, w.worker_duty
from users u
inner join working w on w.worker_id = u.user_id
where u.user_id = "293274";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ?

```
 'SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, u.discription, w.worker_duty FROM users as u
 JOIN working as w ON u.user_id=w.worker_id
 WHERE w.user_id="293274"
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, user.discription, working.working_duty FROM user JOIN working ON user.user_id = working.worker_id WHERE user.user_id="293274"`

Answer (score 0):

Use join as below:

```
     SELECT t1.*,  t2.worker_duty , t2.worker_id  
     from users t1 JOIN working t2
          ON t1.user_id= t2.worker_id 
     WHERE t1.user_id="293274"
```